# how do I make an animations around one character

Tags: javascript, arrays, animation, css-animations

Is there a way to make animation around a number correspond to the number amount? Like number 5 in this picture:

[image: example model]

Comment: You'd probably us JS to calculate a percentage and then use a CSS mask to only show part of a circle

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? Enter a number above 5 for aqua and below 5 for orange.

```js
document.getElementById('applyNum').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('numCon').innerHTML = document.getElementById('numInput').value;

  const v = document.getElementById('numCon').innerHTML;
  if (v >= 5) {
    document.getElementById('numCon').style.borderLeft = '2px solid aqua';
    document.getElementById('numCon').style.borderBottom = '2px solid aqua';
  } else if (v < 5) {
    document.getElementById('numCon').style.borderLeft = '2px solid orange';
    document.getElementById('numCon').style.borderBottom = '2px solid orange';
  }
})
```

```css
#numCon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 5vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<input id='numInput' />
<button id='applyNum'>Apply Number</button>

<div id="numCon"></div>
```

Comment: Well I did not mean for that exactly, but this is good enough for now.

Comment: its not really working when I try to implement it in my html file, new to js so probably me.